# UIGestureRecogniser not calling delegate method

Tags: objective-c, ios, uigesturerecognizer

I am subclassing a UIGestureRecogniser, but for some reason the method

```
- (BOOL)canBePreventedByGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)preventingGestureRecognizer{
```

isn't being called

Any Ideas

[PastBin Link](http://pastebin.com/bfkF18DW)

Comment: `self.delegate = self;` in `initWithBoundsOfSquare:` is not a good idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are mixing two ways to implement the behavior of canBePreventedByGestureRecognizer:

1. Use the delegate class
2. Override the methods, as you are doing

But in your interface you define:

```
UIGestureRecognizer <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
```

***Try to remove the protocol UIGestureRecognizerDelegate?***